# How to ensure order of Cypress request execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cypress

In my Cypress test, I am trying to make calls to two seperate API endpoints.

I'm able to make the calls, but I need to ensure they execute in the correct order.

Below are simplified versions of my requests:

```
cy.request('POST', apiUrl + 'Session', {username: merchant_username}
).as('postSession')

cy.request('POST', apiUrl + 'TestCase', {username: merchant_username}
).as('postTestCase')
```

It's important that the calls execute in this order because some of them depend on values from the others.

I am trying to retrieve `sessionId` from the `postSession` response:

```
cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: apiUrl + 'session',
}).as('postSession')

cy.get('@postSession').should(response => {
         sessionId = response.body.SessionId;
})
```

And then use it in the request body of `postTestCase`:

```
cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: apiUrl + 'TestCase',
            body: {
              "SessionId": sessionId
            }
})
```

If I do `.then()` after `postSession` & place `postTestCase` inside that like so, the request works fine, but I would like to avoid doing that if possible.

```
cy.get('@postToken').should(response => {
         sessionId = response.body.SessionId;
}).then(() => {
  cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: apiUrl + 'TestCase',
  body: {
        "SessionId": sessionId
        }
    })
})
```

I've also tried using `cy.wait()`, but the `sessionId` is blank in the 2nd request then.

```
cy.wait('@postSession')
cy.wait('@postTestCase')
```

Is there a way I can ensure `postSession` is executed before `postTestCase` without placing `postTestCase` inside a `.then()` after `postSession`?

Comment: `.then(() => {`, ***I would like to avoid doing that*** - that's what it's there for, to sequence async operations.

Comment: I just thought there might have been a better approach rather than doing nested requests, but thanks for clearing it up @RichardMatsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the time this answer is posted, there is an open issue on the Cypress GitHub repository with a proposal for `await`, as per this [link](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1417).

So only the "nested" requests way is possible at the moment.

For example of your snippets:

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: apiUrl + 'session',
}).then((response) => {
  const sessionId = response.body.SessionId;
  
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: apiUrl + 'TestCase',
    body: {
      "SessionId": sessionId
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://' + host + '/lending/loan',
            headers: default_headers
        }).then(res => {
             cy.request({})
                .then(res => {})
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was just wondering if there was another way to do this rather than using "nested" requests